# FreeNAS - Identifying Failed Drive in zpool

Tags: zfs, truenas

I have a failed drive in a FreeNas server hosted at OVH.  I need to get the drive swapped, but i'm extremely conscious of them pulling the wrong drive.

FreeNas isn't reporting any serial numbers in it's GUI.  I have done the below so far, I don't know how to either get the drive serial, or better yet blink the LED?

```
    pool: vol0
     state: DEGRADED
    status: One or more devices could not be opened.  Sufficient replicas exist for
        the pool to continue functioning in a degraded state.
action: Attach the missing device and online it using 'zpool online'.
       see: http://illumos.org/msg/ZFS-8000-2Q
      scan: scrub repaired 0 in 15h23m with 0 errors on Sun Jul  9 23:23:55 2017
config:

    NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    vol0                                            DEGRADED     0     0     0
      mirror-0                                      DEGRADED     0     0     0
        4720622759705179538                         UNAVAIL      0    64     0  was /dev/gptid/2a4bad04-4573-11e7-bd76-001e67cb3c7a
        gptid/2af09f67-4573-11e7-bd76-001e67cb3c7a  ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/2b9ad3ca-4573-11e7-bd76-001e67cb3c7a  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/2c440267-4573-11e7-bd76-001e67cb3c7a  ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-2                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/2ce91024-4573-11e7-bd76-001e67cb3c7a  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/2d8f9a88-4573-11e7-bd76-001e67cb3c7a  ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-3                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/2e376cc0-4573-11e7-bd76-001e67cb3c7a  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/2edb2c23-4573-11e7-bd76-001e67cb3c7a  ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-4                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/2f8402f6-4573-11e7-bd76-001e67cb3c7a  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/302bfda0-4573-11e7-bd76-001e67cb3c7a  ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-5                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/30d274f0-4573-11e7-bd76-001e67cb3c7a  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/317ad2a6-4573-11e7-bd76-001e67cb3c7a  ONLINE       0     0     0
    logs
      gptid/cd56ac86-4576-11e7-bd76-001e67cb3c7a    ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Using glabel to get the device:

```
#glabel status | grep 2af09f67-4573-11e7-bd76-001e67cb3c7a
gptid/2af09f67-4573-11e7-bd76-001e67cb3c7a     N/A  mfisyspd5p2
```

What's next?

Updates:

Further reading shows that this problem would be simple if the drives were not attached to a raid controller (all be it in passthrough mode), as then smartctl would provide the information required.  Using mfiutil:

```
#mfiutil show drives
mfi0 Physical Drives:
 9 ( 5589G) JBOD <HGST HUS726060ALS640 A2D0 serial=1EJ48KYH> SCSI-6 E1:S5
10 ( 5589G) JBOD <HGST HUS726060ALS640 A2D0 serial=1EJ49TKH> SCSI-6 E1:S2
11 ( 5589G) JBOD <HGST HUS726060ALS640 A2D0 serial=1EJ48EMH> SCSI-6 E1:S6
12 ( 5589G) JBOD <HGST HUS726060ALS640 A2D0 serial=1EJ4AS6H> SCSI-6 E1:S8
13 ( 5589G) JBOD <HGST HUS726060ALS640 A2D0 serial=1EJ49HWH> SCSI-6 E1:S9
14 ( 5589G) JBOD <HGST HUS726060ALS640 A2D0 serial=1EJ48RDH> SCSI-6 E1:S10
15 ( 5589G) JBOD <HGST HUS726060ALS640 A2D0 serial=1EJ48NVH> SCSI-6 E1:S1
16 ( 5589G) JBOD <HGST HUS726060ALS640 A2D0 serial=1EJ49T1H> SCSI-6 E1:S11
17 ( 5589G) JBOD <HGST HUS726060ALS640 A2D0 serial=1EJ48T9H> SCSI-6 E1:S4
18 ( 5589G) JBOD <HGST HUS726060ALS640 A2D0 serial=1EJ4BAMH> SCSI-6 E1:S7
19 ( 5589G) JBOD <HGST HUS726060ALS640 A2D0 serial=1EJ4A0JH> SCSI-6 E1:S3
20 ( 5589G) JBOD <HGST HUS726060ALS640 A2D0 serial=1EJ4AX8H> SCSI-6 E1:S0
21 (  149G) JBOD <INTEL SSDSC2BB16 0370 serial=BTWL340106TD160MGN> SATA E2:S4
```

I now have serial numbers and devices, how do i map the two together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i couldn't find a way to map the mfiutil to a device.  I'm sure there is a way but it escapes me.  In the end i rebooted into the raid controller bios and luckily as the drive was completely dead it was showing in the controller.

I think if i had studied megacli i could have realised this without rebooting, which would have been better.

But in the end mfisyspd5 actually mapped to E1:S9, serial 1EJ49HWH

But overall, if you want to run ZFS, don't use a RAID controller even in passthrough, just get a HBA.  Will save you hassle in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You have an LSI MegaRaid (or similar) if it's using the **mfi** driver.  Use `mfiutil`:

`mfiuti show drives`

`mfiutil locate drive on`
should light the corresponding drive if possible.

[FreeBSD mfiutil man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mfiutil&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html)

Comment: How strange, at the moment you posted this i found the same suggestion after reading the freenas forums, i've done this and updated the question - i'm struggling to map the mfiutil output to mfisyspd5 ?

Comment: You have mifisyspd[0-11], no?  I'd bet these map to your mifiutil SCSI numbers.